# Fourier transform with discontinuous derivative

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function with compact support. Assume further that $f$ is smooth, expect for at the origin where it has a discontinuous derivative
$$
\Delta := \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} ( f'(\epsilon)-f'(-\epsilon)) \neq 0.
$$
Define
$$
g(x) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy~ k^2 e^{ik(x-y)} f(y)
$$
and
$$
I := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, g(x).
$$
Assuming that I can freely interchange the integrals, in $I$ I can pull in the $x$ integral, which gives a delta distribution $\delta(k)$ and therefore
$$
I = 0.
$$
On the other hand, let us calculate $I$ by partially integrating twice
$$
I = - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy~  e^{ik(x-y)} f''(y) = - 2\pi \Big ( \int_{-\infty}^0 dx\, f''(x) + \int_0^{\infty} dx\, f''(x)  \Big ) = - 2\pi \Delta.
$$
(I am aware that this is probably illegal, since $f'$ is not absolutely continuous, right?)
This suggests that $g$ has an additional delta function term
$$
 - 2\pi \Delta \, \delta(x),
$$
which does not appear in the first calculation.

This is a contradiction, so obviously I have made an error in one (or both) of the calculations.

Is $g$ well-defined for the function $f$ at hand? Is it sensible to write
$$
g(x) = - 2\pi f''(x)
$$
in the sense of distributions? So that for a suitable test function $\phi$, we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx~ g(x) \phi(x) = 2\pi \Delta \, \phi(0) + 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx~ f'(x) \phi'(x).
$$
Should the $\Delta$ term be there or not?

Comment: $f(x) + \Delta \exp(-|x|)$ is continuously differentiable, so we should have $I[f] = -\Delta I[\exp(-|x|)]$. Then $\int\int\int k^2 e^{ik(x-y)-|y|}dydkdx$ is just a number you can compute.

Comment: I find that $I[\exp(-|x|)] = 2 \int \int k^2  (e^{ikx}- \frac{e^{ikx}}{1+k^2}) dk dx = 2\pi \int (2 \delta(x) - \exp(-|x|) ) dx = 0$. So this means that the $\Delta$ term is absent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity
$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k^2 \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx} \, dk
= 2\pi \, f''(-x)
$
is only valid if $f'$ is continuous. Otherwise one must replace $f''$ with the distributional second derivative.

Let $f$ be as in the question and define $\partial^2 f$ by
$$
\partial^2 f(x) = \begin{cases}
f''(x) & (x \neq 0) \\
0 & (x = 0)
\end{cases}
$$
and let us denote the distributional second derivative with $D^2 f.$ Then we have
$$
D^2 f = \partial^2 f + (f'(0^+)-f'(0^-)) \, \delta.
$$
Now, when we integrate this we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} D^2 f(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} \partial^2 f(x) \, dx
+ \int_{0}^{\infty} \partial^2 f(x) \, dx
+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f'(0^+)-f'(0^-)) \, \delta(x) \, dx
= (f'(0^-)-f'(-\infty)) + (f'(\infty)- f'(0^+)) + (f'(0^+)-f'(0^-))
= 0.
$$